# Joomla accessing templates folder

Tags: templates, joomla, directory

With Joomla using the online-administrator menu, how can i have access to templates folder? (I am not talking about running the server in my own computer, but using the cloudacess thing).

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand you. May be just for me. Sorry. What do you mean by `access to templates folder`? What do you have now and what do you want to get? Maybe it is not my job. But I would like to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you login on the backend (using your administrator panel - typically www.yourdomain.com/administrator) you can then go to 'Extensions -> Template Manager'

That will get you access to the various templates within your templates folder via the backend of Joomla.

You can then click on any of those templates to access the HTML/CSS of each template.  If you wish to edit anything further or utilize template overrides for components you'll need to access that folder via an FTP program.

Hope this helps - if you need clarification - let me know!

Comment: i already know what you are telling me. I would like to have access to the templates folder, because they way you are telling me, i only have access to css and index.php files. How about images? I want to have access to the website images, and thats the thing i dont know how do

Comment: You'll have to use an ftp program to get access to the server.  Filezilla is a great one to use.  The default path to get to it will be something like: yourjoomladirectory/templates/yourtemplate - that will give you access to all the php files, images, overrides and everything else.

Comment: Were you able to gain FTP access?

Comment: I'm also stuck with this situation. I managed to get FTP access but something must be wrong. I'm only getting one folder: 'incoming' and a file: '.ftpquota'. Please can you help me, I just want to change my favicon.ico!